# Check if method requires a parameter using annotation and reflect

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

The question: Is there a way to do code inspection for a method and check if it doesn't have a parameter and warn me before compilation, or even give me a warning in my IDE.

Let's say I have an annotation `@Initialize`

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Initialize {
    int priority();
}
```

And with reflect, I can invoke methods that are annotated with `@Initialize`

```
public static void initMethods(Initializable clazz) {
    TreeMap<Integer, Method> methods = prioritizedMethods(clazz.getClass().getDeclaredMethods());
    methods.forEach((priority, method) -> {
        try {
            method.setAccessible(true);
            Logger.debug("Invoking " + method.getName() + "...");
            method.invoke(clazz);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            Logger.debug("Failed to invoke " + method.getName());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

`prioritzedMethods(Method[] method)` is where I check for annotation.

```
private static TreeMap<Integer, Method> prioritizedMethods(Method[] methods) {
    HashMap<Integer, Method> taggedMethods = new HashMap<>();
    for (Method method : methods) {
        if (method.isAnnotationPresent(Initialize.class)) {
            Initialize meta = method.getAnnotation(Initialize.class);
            taggedMethods.put(meta.priority(), method);
        }
    }
    return new TreeMap<>(taggedMethods);
}
```

I want to make sure that all methods that are annotated with `@Initialize` do not have any parameter.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the [`Supplier` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html), possibly combined with a [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html)? No reflection & annotations required. Over all, this sounds like an [XY problem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a framework for such common requirement. See [`deannotation-checker`](https://github.com/XDean/Deannotation-checker).

The only thing you should do is add `@CheckMethod` on your annotation.

```
@CheckMethod(argCount = 0, returnType = @CheckType(void.class))
public @interface Init {
   ...
}
```

Now your annotation has ability to restrict the annotated method. If you use it like

```
@Init
public void func(int i) {
  ...
}
```

You will get compile error

```
[5,15] Must only have 0 arguments.
```

If you IDE support (I'm using eclipse and m2e-apt plugin), you can get the error when save the file.

[image]

Comment: Now I'm still test and write doc. It will be release into maven central in several days.

Comment: This was it! Thanks for this.

Comment: @EthanBacurio Hi, I have released into central repository. You can follow the [README](https://github.com/XDean/Deannotation-checker) to use the checker framework. If there is any problem, please let me know.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just waiting for your latest artifact (0.1.2) to be reflected in the Central Repository

Comment: @EthanBacurio Now it is `0.2.0-SNAPSHOT`. `0.1.2` has no `@CheckMethod` feature.

Answer (score 2):

`method.getParameterTypes().length == 0` if and only if `method` has no parameters. ([Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getParameterTypes()))

Comment: Yes, I get this one; however, what I wanted to achieve is for my IDE to give me or other people a warning when we try to annotate a method with a parameter.

Comment: No way to check this with a standard IDE without writing your own IDE extension.

Comment: @EthanBacurio One could do this, of course, by writing an own annotation processor. This would have the added benefit that it is IDE-independent. But again, you can avoid the whole hustle by using an interface instead of an annotation.